# Why Flutter copies the src of standard libraries to sky_engine?

Tags: dart, flutter

Since [dart:ffi](https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/tree/master/sdk/lib/ffi) is available from Dart `2.2.0-dev.2.0`, I've been trying to use that library. [The sample app](https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/tree/master/samples/ffi/sqlite) works fine for me and I also tried to use it for my Flutter app but I couldn't call it with `import "dart:ffi"`, although Flutter on my machine was `HEAD` of `master` that used Dart `2.3.0-dev.0.0`.

I checked what happened, then I found that [sky_engine](https://github.com/flutter/engine/tree/master/sky/packages/sky_engine#flutter-engine) didn't contain `ffi.dart` while it contained other libraries (e.g. "dart:core"). Also I noticed that the source files of those libraries were copied from `$FLUTTER_ROOT/bin/cache/dart-sdk/lib` to `$FLUTTER_ROOT/bin/cache/pkg/sky_engine` using [BUILD.gn](https://github.com/flutter/engine/blob/master/sky/packages/sky_engine/BUILD.gn) or [_embedder.yaml](https://github.com/flutter/engine/blob/master/sky/packages/sky_engine/lib/_embedder.yaml) and that seemed to be why I couldn't use the `dart:ffi` in my Flutter app.

However, in the first place, why does Flutter need sky_engine, which is "the interface between Dart and the Flutter Engine"? Why not calling them directly without this glue code?

Comment: Hi did you find the solution?

Comment: @ch271828n Nope.

Comment: Ah sad to hear that :(

Comment: Sky was the original name for Flutter - just imagine it was called `flutter_engine` :)

Comment: Would you consider editing the question to include a [repro]. Also I think you want to clarify the title as I imagine the answer to "why flutter copies..." can be opinion based, but if you instead were asking something like "how to import dart:ffi" that would increase the chances for an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Flutter has a good [documentation for FFI](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/platform-integration/c-interop) to be able to call native C APIs. Adding `import 'dart:ffi' as ffi;` on the Flutter app works without issues as of my testing with Flutter 2.5. If you're able to provide a [minimal repro](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your issue, this will help folks to understand the question better.

As for the question on why sky_engine is used by Flutter, that's just simply because it's the "flutter_engine" - similar to what has been already mentioned in the comments.